# How to get index values with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, group-by, multi-index

I have a code which iterates every company group:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Price': [12, 9, 11, 10, 7, 21, 23],
                     'Date': ['1991-01-01', '1991-02-01', '1991-03-01', '1991-01-01', '1991-02-01', '1991-03-01', '1991-04-01'],
                     'Company': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']})
data.set_index(['Date', 'Company'], inplace=True)
for company_name, df_company in data.groupby('Company'):
    company_index = df_company.index.get_level_values('Date').max()
    last_values = df_company.loc[company_index].iloc[0]
    # some functions
```

Here, I am trying to get latest of df_company and will use it in some functions. However, `df_company.loc[company_index].iloc[0]`, does not include "Date" column. How can I change the code to get latest of df_company with `"Date"` column. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
for company_name, df_company in data.groupby('Company'):
    print(company_name)
    dates = df_company.index.get_level_values('Date')
    # tail is optional, use .iloc[-1] for a Series
    last_values = df_company[dates == dates.max()].tail(1) 
    print(last_values)
```

output:

```
A
                    Price
Date       Company       
1991-03-01 A           11
B
                    Price
Date       Company       
1991-04-01 B           23
```